# hapi/lab (and jest): is there a way to have a describe block in a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, integration-testing, hapi

I am working on a test script using hapi/lab in nodejs.
I would like to have a describe block that is using hapi.server to inject http options (to simulate integration testing).
Something like:

main.test.js:
...

```
describe('main', async () => {
   before(async () => {...}

   describe('inner-main', async() => {
      **externalDescribe**(some params that exists in this file)

      it('test specific to this file', async () => {...})
   })
})
```

externalFile.test.js:
...

```
function **externalDescribe**(some params) {
  describe('external', async () => {
      it('first it', async () => {
        ...
      })
  })
}
```

Or something similar.